# Event variable in Google sheets doesn't fetch a value of the cell to which I do copy and paste a value from another cell

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My event variable gets a `value` of an edited cell just fine when I edit a cell manually, but completely ignores when I do paste or paste special.

For example, when I write `foo` in A1 cell manually, the event variable has `foo` in its value property at the moment:

```
console.log(e.value);// foo
```

However, when I copy `foo` from another cell and paste it to A1 cell (with right click menu or `Ctrl + V`), the event variable has `undefined`.

```
console.log(e.value);// undefined
```

I tried this test in onEdit function and it fired, so this `paste` seems to be recognized as an `edit event` by GAS and Google sheets, but just not fetching a value from the pasted cell.

I want the event variable to receive a new value from the pasted cell when I do paste.

But it doesn't make it at all!

Please point me to how to do it right or tell me it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, how about directly retrieving the value from the edited range? So how about the following script?

#### From:

```
console.log(e.value);
```

#### To:

```
console.log(e.range.getValue());
```

or, when several cells are edited, you can also use the following script.

```
console.log(e.range.getValues());
```

#### Reference:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Thank you. I tried and  it worked.  The problem was probably that I was trying to do paste for a range of multiple cells. `e.value` seems  `Only available if the edited range is a single cell.` according to the reference.

Comment: To achieve my goal, I have to do this in multiple cells using `getValues()` but it seems to take a while to modify my code. It's going to be a bit bothering task...

Comment: @jazzGeek Thank you for replying and adding more information. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.